# Какую структуру данных использовать для сохранения в SQLite?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

Я получаю данные с сервера в таком виде:

```
[
    {
        "first": "first",
        "second": "second",
        "third": "third",
        "fourth": "fourth",
        "fifth": "fifth",
        "sixth": "sixth"
    },
    {
        "seventh": "seventh",
        "eights": "eights",
        "ninth": "ninth",
        "tenth": "tenth",
        "eleventh": "eleventh",
        "twelves": "twelves"
    }
]
```

Полученные данные мне нужно вывести в ListView.

Запрос в ретрофите:

```
@POST("/zapros")
    Call< -??- > getExercisesFromBlock(@Body Token idToken);
```

Запрос в классе:

```
private void getInfo() {
        Token token = new Token();
        token.idToken = mIdToken;
        Call< -? не знаю ?- > call = mRetrofit.getInfoFromServer(token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback< -? не знаю ?- >() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call< -??- > call, Response< -??- > response) {
                mList = response.body();
                mSQLite.saveInfo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call< -??- > call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
```

Сохранение в базе данных:

```
public void saveExercises( -??- ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        Model model = new Model();
        cv.put( -все данные- );

        db.insert(NAMETABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

Еще не знаю, как потом загрузку с базы написать.

Comment: Пока вы не поясните для чего вам их сохранять и какие к ним требования, то можете сохранять хоть весь JSON как строку )

Comment: *И я хочу сохранить это в SQLite.* Сие не может быть основанием для выбора типа. Ориентироваться следует на то, что с этими данными будет делаться. Только возвращать as is - это одно. Обрабатывать - другое. Выполнять поиск по содержимому - третье. А в общем случае в SQLite сохранять JSON с чисто числовыми данными лучше в BLOB - компактнее.

Comment: Извините. Мне нужно потом эти данные вывести в ListView. Все данные будут String

Comment: @AntonPankratov дополнения к вопросу стоит включать в сам вопрос (кнопка "править").

Comment: *Мне нужно потом эти данные вывести в ListView. Все данные будут String* Тогда я вообще не понимаю, при чём тут SQLite, когда проблема чисто в Java...

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас переделаю вопрос